# t test between multiple columns with conditions

Tags: r

I am trying to run a t-test between values in R. The dataset looks somewhat like this:

```
Name Date       maths_marks     science_marks     english_marks    history_marks
a    1/1/2018      67               86                78                54 
a    2/1/2018       0               46                64                28
a    3/1/2018      95               81                76                56 
a    4/1/2018      76               75                 0                43
a    5/1/2018      67               86                78                54
a    6/1/2018      95               81                76                56
a    7/1/2018       0               46                64                28
```

I am using adply to conduct ttest between different columns but I also want to include the condition to exclude 0 marks records when t test is conducted containing that subject record.

For example if a t_test is conducted between maths and science marks I want to exclude records for date 2/1/2018 as maths is 0 and conduct t_test between remaining records. Same case for other t_tests.

Can someone please help me the required query.

Comment: You should consult a statistician.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just replace all the 0 scores with `NA` and run the tests?

```
> marks[marks == 0] <- NA_character_
> marks
  Name     Date maths_marks science_marks english_marks history_marks
1    a 1/1/2018          67            86            78            54
2    b 2/1/2018        <NA>            46            64            28
... and so on

> t.test(as.numeric(marks[,2]),as.numeric(marks[,3]))

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  as.numeric(marks[, 2]) and as.numeric(marks[, 3])
t = -11.889, df = 4.133, p-value = 0.0002377
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -93.52597 -58.47403
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
        4        80
```

Comment: So for example if  ttest is conducted between maths and science marks and if I replace 0 with NA , then both maths and science marks record for 2/1/2018 will not be considered or it will be considered for science and not maths?

Comment: The first line just replaces all the zeroes in your data frame with `NA` so any `t.tests` between the columns you choose should work.

Comment: Why do you turn the columns into characters by assigning `NA_character_` and then turn them again into numeric? Just assign `NA` instead and leave the column classes as they are.